Continuous Speech Recognition on Android failed after 3-4 hours
I implemented Continuous Speech Recognition on Android 14. Below code I am using:
public async Task<string> Listen(CultureInfo culture,
    IProgress<string> recognitionResult,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   
    try
    {
      
        var taskResult = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        listener = new SpeechRecognitionListener
        {

            Error = ex => {
                taskResult.TrySetException(new Exception("Failure in speech engine - " + ex));
                },
            PartialResults = sentence =>
            {
                recognitionResult?.Report(sentence);
            },
            Results = sentence => taskResult.TrySetResult(sentence)
        };


        speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(Android.App.Application.Context,
        new ComponentName(
    "com.google.android.tts",
    "com.google.android.apps.speech.tts.googletts.service.GoogleTTSRecognitionService"
));

        if (speechRecognizer is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Speech recognizer is not available");
        }
  
        speechRecognizer.SetRecognitionListener(listener);
        speechRecognizer.StartListening(CreateSpeechIntent(culture));
        
        await using (cancellationToken.Register(() =>
        {
            StopRecording();
            taskResult.TrySetCanceled();

        }))
        {

            return await taskResult.Task;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;

    }
    finally
    {
        StopRecording();
        
    }

}



private void StopRecording()
{
    if (speechRecognizer != null)
    {
        speechRecognizer?.StopListening();
        speechRecognizer?.Destroy();
        speechRecognizer = null;
    }
}

private Android.Content.Intent CreateSpeechIntent(CultureInfo culture)
{
    var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);


    string language = culture.Name; 

    var javaLocale = Java.Util.Locale.ForLanguageTag(language).ToString();
    intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, javaLocale);
    
    intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguagePreference, javaLocale);
    intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
    intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraCallingPackage, Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName);
    intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraOnlyReturnLanguagePreference, true);
    
    intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);

    intent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPartialResults, false);

    return intent;
}


Randomly after 3-4 hours of successful working the recognition stop - the mic icon is not shown anymore. The error which is relevant to the issue I think is:

2024-09-08 04:18:13.199  1382-1382  ActivityManager         system_server                        W  bindService exceeded max service connection number per process, callerApp:system intent:Intent { act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.apps.speech.tts.googletts.service.GoogleTTSRecognitionService }

After stop Speech Recognition and Synthesis from Google and restart my application it start to work again
Do you know what is max service connection number per process ?
Why it happen? What I am doing wrong in code?


From the source code, the error is due to numberOfConnections()>= mMaxServiceConnectionsPerProcess. I think it's caused by 3-4 hours of successful working, reaches its mMaxServiceConnectionsPerProcess. 2. You may set other properties to ensure not reach the maxserviceconnection. Also, you can refer to this similar thread.


@AlexandarMay-MSFT thanks for hint. But where I can pass mMaxServiceConnectionsPerProcess? Could you provide example? The similar thread you recommended similar to what I did, but we do not know if it has similar issue

This para:mMaxServiceConnectionsPerProcess is set by design, you probably can't change it.

so what is solution?

Consider logging an issue via:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues
